# Where did my assault rifle go?

Tags: mass-effect-3

On the moon of Pavalon, I picked up some sort of Reaper-esque weapon that had only 1 shot during the mission's final fight.  Not wanting to use the shot immediately, I swapped weapons (PC version, using scroll wheel) to my pistol.  However, when I halted the game to change weapons, I could not select my assault rifle (which I had equipped when I picked up this weapon) nor could I find this special Reaper-type weapon.

Finishing the mission seemed to have given me my rifle back, but obviously I lost the shot of this gun and the use of my rifle (I'm a Soldier so imagine the fun I had trying to kill Brutes with a Pistol and Sniper rifle)

Any idea what happened here and is there a way for me to regain my gun or am I stuck like this until I reload/finish the mission?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't carry Heavy Weapons around in this game. If you switch from them, you drop them.

When you pick up a Heavy Weapon, it temporarily replaces your current weapon from the weapon select wheel - the reason you couldn't find your Assault Rifle was because you *technically* still had it as your active weapon.

So you then switched to your pistol, which dropped the Heavy Weapon (on the ground nearby, able to be picked up again).

After this, your Assault Rifle should have been selectable again. Did you only try to switch to the assault rifle while you were carrying the Reaper Blackstar (the Heavy Weapon you found)?

Comment: I did, nothing ever happened nor could I find the Blackstar on the battlefield where I swapped.

Comment: @TylerShads is this reproducible?

Comment: Finished the mission and I'm done for the night, I'll have to see what I can do to try to repo this.

Comment: Just tried again, seems to have been a glitch as I got no-repo on it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug. I've had the same issue and I was only able to get my gun back by loading an earlier save. Otherwise you are forced to finish the mission without your gun.

I've had that more than once but it happens relatively rarely (2-3 times per playthrough) so it's not easily reproducible. Hopefully they will fix that soon.